# How to return optional from useAppSelector / createSelector?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have this selector in `slice.ts`:

```
export const authnResS = (state: RootState) => state.slice.authnRes
```

And this appSelector in `hooks.ts`:

```js
export const authnRes = useAppSelector(authnResS)
```

When I bring cursor over `authnRes` it says type is `const authnRes: AuthnRes` but it can be `null` also. How can I mark it as it not always exist?

Maybe it is relating but when running `yarn build` I got this error:

```
> Build error occurred
TypeError: Cannot read property 'useContext' of null
    at exports.useContext (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/react/cjs/react.production.min.js:24:118)
    at useReduxContext (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useReduxContext.js:27:46)
    at useSelector (/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/Tikex/Portal/Team/node_modules/react-redux/lib/hooks/useSelector.js:53:9)
```

`slice.ts`:

```js
import { createSelector } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import axios from 'axios'
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {
    AuthnRes,
    UserDTO,
} from './Types'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import type { RootState } from './store'

interface StateType {
    authnRes?: AuthnRes
}

const initialState: StateType = {
    authnRes: null,
}

const namespace = 'slice'

export const me = createAsyncThunk(`${namespace}/me`, async () => {
    const { data } = await axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'me',
        headers: { crossDomain: true },
    })
    return data
})

const slice = createSlice({
    name: 'slice',
    initialState,
    reducers: {

    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        .addCase(me.fulfilled, (state, { payload }) => {
                state.authnRes = payload
            })
    },
})
```

If I replace in each component form this:

```
import { authnRes } from '../../../tikexModule/hooks'
```

to this:

```
import { useAppSelector } from '../../../tikexModule/hooks'
const authnRes = useAppSelector((state) => state.slice?.authnRes)
```

I got no error!! Why?

Comment: Can you share the entire code of your slice.ts? Or at least of the `createSlice` portion?

Comment: I added relevant part of `slice.ts`

Answer (score 1):

There's a type mismatch on your `initialState`. The `authnRes` is defined as `AuthnRes` or `undefined` but the initialState assign null to it. Try to change `StateType` to accept null. I created a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhAIEEFcBcAsB2AlApgZ3ABwDYEMBjVeAexwBNUAncAS0VmoDNDVwRgBYAKHsapZEocJGkwBvHuGnhYJANapEALnDpYVegHMA3DwC%20PHn2atwAZVh5GAFQCeWNpO4zweESgwB%20VTASf0Ax4CEkR1OkRaWFo8HEtrVGV42wc2AF5wZ1d3fzFVRGgcHAMgA) that demonstrate it.

```js
interface StateType {
    authnRes?: AuthnRes
}
```

That said, the build error is caused by the use of `useAppSelector` outside a React component or custom hooks in your *hooks.ts*. You cannot export a variable with the return value of `useAppSelector` because it needs the Redux context which is not available on that scope. It's one of the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). Probably fixing both this error your TypeScript compiler will understand the correct type of your state.

If you haven't done yet, I suggest you to install a linter, like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/) and its relevant plugins like [TS plugins](https://typescript-eslint.io/docs/linting/) and [React Hooks plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks). Using it you'll see all these warnings while you are writing.

Comment: I see, I can not export `export const authnRes => useAppSelector(authnResS)` but I can export `export const authnRes = () => useAppSelector(authnResS)` right? And use as `authnRes()`!

Comment: Yes, but it's better to name it `useAuthnRes` to follow the hooks convention (hooks name must start with `use`). In practice, you are creating a custom hook. You can follow the [custom hook guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) for further information.

`export const useAuthnRes = () => useAppSelector(authnResS)`

Comment: I tried, but faceing a new problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72182946/how-to-intialize-empty-redux-store