# How to intialize empty Redux store?

Tags: redux, next.js, redux-thunk

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'store' of 'useReduxContext(...)' as it is null.
```

Try initialize in `slice.ts` like this:

```js
interface StateType {
    authnRes?: AuthnRes
    selectedOrganizationId?: string
    selectedEventId?: string
    soldTicketRes?: SoldTicketRes
    isRegistrationInProgress?: Boolean
}

const initialState: StateType = {}

const tikexAPI = createSlice({
    name: 'tikexAPI',
    initialState,
```

And export selectors in `slice.ts` like this:

```js
export const authnResS = (state: RootState) => state.tikexAPI.authnRes

export const userDTOS = createSelector(
    [authnResS],
    (authnRes?: AuthnRes) => authnRes?.data
)
```

and have this in `hooks.ts`:

```js
export const useAppDispatch = () => useDispatch<AppDispatch>()
export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector

export const authnRes = (): AuthnRes | undefined => useAppSelector(authnResS)
export const userDTO = (): UserDTO | undefined => useAppSelector(userDTOS)
```

_app.tsx:

```js
import { store } from '../tikexModule/store'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {

    const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => <Layout>{page}</Layout>)

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Seems like you haven't initialized the Redux store with the [Provider](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start#provide-the-redux-store-to-react). Can you share the code where you initialize the Redux store and where you render the Redux Provider?

Comment: I did use `Provider`

Comment: @János Some general advice: Don't use optional properties in the state so much, it makes handling it difficult. It's usually easier to have empty or null values for something like `selectedEventId`. If you know it's a string, initialize it as an empty string. `isRegistrationInProgress` should always be false (don't use a boolean to model 3 different states).

Comment: It is really sad if I have to use empty string to represent the missing value